# Moto G 2nd Gen Photos disappearing

Tags: internal-storage, photos, gallery, motorola-moto-g2

I am using Moto g 2nd Gen. I have a weird problem with my phone. If I took any photos & leave those  in my phone. After 2-3 months I cant able to view those photos. Gallery shows a Grey image as thumbnail instead. If I touch one of those photos to view, Again grey image. I copied to my Computer to view that no use :(
I even changed my memory card to Sandisk. 
Most affected photos are in Phone memory. I lost some of my precious photos.

Why this is happening?